# Fixed field of $G(K/\Bbb Q)\cap V$

Tags: galois-theory, symmetric-groups, galois-extensions, galois-representations

I've been trying to solve the following question, but I wasn't able to.

> Given $p\in\Bbb Q[x]$ an irreducible quartic polynomial, and $a,b,c,d$ its roots, consider $K=\Bbb Q(a,b,c,d)$ its splitting field, and $G=G(K/\Bbb Q)\subseteq S_4$ its Galois group. Prove that $G\cap V$, with $V=\{\textit{Id},(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ the Klein group, has $L=\Bbb Q(ab+cd,ac+bd,ad+bc)$ as fixed field.

I see that each element of $V$ fixes one of the three generators of $L$, but that's not enough, since every generator must be fixed. I also know that we can get rid of one of the generators using Vieta's formulas, but there are still two and it's not clear $V$ fixes both of them. I've read something related to this problem about a cubic resolvent, but I've never used that before, so it's unlikely it's necessary for the solution.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows immediately from the definition of $V$ that it fixes $\alpha= ab+cd, \beta= ac+bd, \gamma= ad+bc$. Conversely, it is easily seen (by tedious checking)that any permutation of the roots $a,b,c,d$ fixing $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ belongs to $V$. Hence $L=\mathbf Q(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ is the fixed field of $G\cap V$, and $G/G\cap V$ is the Galois group of $L/\mathbf Q$.

NB. 1) The "resolvent cubic" of your irreducible quartic $P(X)$ is $(X-\alpha)(X-\beta)(X-\gamma)$. The name comes from the fact that the degree $n$ of the splitting field of the resolvent determines completely $G$, unless when $n=2$, in which case a supplementary computation is necessary.
2) The base field need not be $\mathbf Q$, it could be any field of characterisic $\neq 2$.

Comment: Why does it follow immediately that $V$ fixes $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$? The way I see it, each element of $V$ fixes one of them, but not the other two.

Comment: That's precisely the problem I'm stuck with.

Comment: I give the details for the reader to check. To avoid errors, I renumber the roots as $x_1, x_2,...$ instead of $a,b...$. Let us apply to $\alpha$ the non trivial permutations in V:
  
Permutation (1,2)(3,4): $\alpha=x_1x_2+x_3x_4$ is fixed ; permutation (1,3)(2,4): $\beta=x_1x_3+x_2x_4$ goes to $x_1x_3+x_4x_2$ goes to $x_3x_1+x_4x_2=\beta$ ; permutation (1,4)(2,3): $\gamma=x_1 x_4+x_2x_3$ goes to $x_1x_4+x_3x_2$ goes to $x_4x_1+x_3x_2=\gamma$.

So we checked that every permutation in V fixes every $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$.

Comment: @Darsen   See my comment

Comment: Oh, I'm such a scatterbrain... I was applying the permutations to $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ in the wrong way. Thanks!

Comment: Lastly, could you indicate how the converse would be proven? The thing is I can't be sure if some permutation fixes an element or not; for example, it would seem that the permutation $(1234)$ doesn't fix $\alpha$, since $r_1r_2+r_3r_4$ would go to $r_2r_3+r_4r_1$, but how do I know they're not the same thing?

Comment: @Darsen      To avoid "tedious checking", let us organize the calculations according to $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, i.e. following the cubic resolvent. Introduce $H_{\alpha} = <V, (1,2)>$ (isomorphic to $D_8$), which is the fixator of $\alpha$. Then, with obvious notations,$V=H_{\alpha} \cap H_{\beta} \cap H_{\gamma}$ and $S_4 =H_{\alpha} \cup (1,3)H_{\alpha} \cup (1,4)H_{\alpha}$. It follows that if $s\in G$ fixes ${\alpha}, {\beta}, {\gamma}$, then $s$ belongs to $V$.